# Joomla! modal, on close refresh page under condition

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

Using Joomla! v2.5 and modal to open a new popup

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=my_view" class="modal" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 600}}">
```

User will have some options (links) such as info/delete/lock.

After selecting(clicking) an option and clicking the "close" button, I need to either just close the modal or close the modal and refresh the page.

I can ALWAYS refresh the page using something like this

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=my_view" class="modal" rel="{handler:'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 600},onClose:function(){var js =window.location.reload();}}">
```

but I need to refresh the page under conditions (eg. user clicked "delete" => refresh, user clicked "info" => do nothing)

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So, in Joomla! 2.5 the `modal` popups are handled by the [SqueezeBox](http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/) script (version 1.3).

Set your `onClose` handler to call your own Javascript method, so this:

```js
onClose:function(){var js =window.location.reload();}
```

Changes to:

```js
onClose:function(){checkUserChoice();}
```

Or if you keep your Javascript neatly namespaced (as recommended)

```js
onClose:function(){mycomponent.checkUserChoice();}
```

Have your `checkUserChoice()` set to make the decision:

```js
mycomponent.checkUserChoice = function () {
    userChoice = document.id('userOption).value;
    if(userChoice == 'delete') {
        // refresh our page
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Then load your custom Javascript file into the view:

```php
// Get the document object
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('path/to/myscript.js');
```

Or, if you only have the one small method to load:

```js
$myscript = <<<'JS'
mycomponent.checkUserChoice = function () {
    userChoice = document.id('userOption).value;
    if(userChoice == 'delete') {
        // refresh our page
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
JS;

$document->addScriptDeclaration($myscript);
```

Comment: yeah, but how can I "pass" the user's choise from the modal to parent?

Answer (score 0):

For the onClose handler, I'd recommend having it call your own custom JS method.  In that method, handle your custom logic for determining whether to refresh the page or not.